# CakePHP extend currency formatting

Tags: php, cakephp, formatting

I need to extend the number helper to include other currencies. Using the "addFormat" function in the number helper, I have created a new "CurrenciesHelper" to add these currencies.

```
<?php

class CurrenciesHelper extends NumberHelper {
```

I know I need to make it possible for this helper to run this function **immediately**. What am I missing to contain this so it runs and adds this format?

```
     $this->Number->addFormat('CAD', array(
        'before'=>'$',
        'after' => false,
        'zero' => 0,
        'places' => 2,
        'thousands' => '.',
        'decimals' => ',',
        'negative' => '()',

}
```

Comment: Why extend the helper? Why not just `addFormat()` and then use `currency()` - http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1453/currency

Comment: Because I was to have a helper add all the formats I need (6 currencies) instead of having to 'addFormat()' on every line that I use currency. The idea is to add the helper 'Currencies' and have it add all of them to the available currencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PREVIOUS ANSWER CHANGED: Due to position of functions, after the fact. Had to change to:

```
function __beforeRender(){
}
```

Was causing overwriting of other custom currencies.

> By encapsulating it in a construct
>   function, it run on helper
>   construction. I was sure to include
>   the parent constructor just in case.
>
> ```
> function __construct() {
>     parent::__construct();
>     // code goes here
> }
> ```

Comment: Downvote: This does not answer the question and it is outdated and it is also not the "cakephp way" to do things.

Answer (score 4):

Starting CakePHP 2.1, you don't need to extend the helper to get this done. `NumberHelper` has been re-factored into `CakeNumber` class. If you go through [the code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/9624c27ef47937948da14977fc78b605496062e7/lib/Cake/Utility/CakeNumber.php), you can see that the formats are now stored as a static array.

That helps us configure currency formats within `app/Config/core.php`, like the following:

```
App::uses( 'CakeNumber', 'Utility' );

CakeNumber::addFormat( 
    'CAD', 
    array(
       'before' => '$ ', 'after' => false, 
       'zero' => 0, 'places' => 2, 'thousands' => '.',
       'decimals' => ',', 'negative' => '()', 'escape' => true
    ) 
);

// ... and any more definitions to follow.
```

Once your currency definitions are part of the core configuration, you can use them in any view using `NumberHelper` like `$this->Number->currency( $c, 'CAD' )`.

Comment: I preferred to do include this in my bootstrap file. Please comment if you think I'm wrong. Also, I added this line: `CakeNumber::defaultCurrency('ARS');`